# How to determine the charge of a $W$ boson in a Feynman diagram?

Tags: charge, conservation-laws, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

As the title says, I am not sure in what situations there is a W$^+$ boson and when there is a W$^-$ boson. My lecturer explained to me that you can view it either as the $W$ boson supplying a charge or removing a charge, and so either direction is fine. I am still a bit unsure of whether I understood her correctly, and in the Feynman diagrams I see, the $W$ boson usually has one specific charge. Right now I am drawing the diagram below, and I don't know what sign the $W$ should have. The total charge on each side of the first vertex is +2/3, and I don't know what that means for the $W$ since it has integer charge.

[image]

Comment: I always pictured it as $c$ goes to $s$ so 'its charge gets reduced', i.e. a 'positive charge flies off' ergo its $W^+$ which is also evident from its decay to $K^+$.

Comment: Do you understand what the charges of the various quarks and antiquarks are? If so, just use charge conservation at each vertex.

Comment: A $W^+$  and an s leave the  c vertex, or else, equivalently, a   $W^-$ joins the c to produce an s.

Comment: @Ghoster I was using charge conservation when saying that the charge at each side of the first vertex is +2/3. I don't know what that means for the sign of the W.

Answer (score 1):

So your included graph is not really a Feynman diagram, it's a time ordered diagram. In that case, the charge is clear, based on conservation at the vertices, and the direction of time flow.

The actual Feynman diagram for this process would have a vertical line for the $W$, and it would represent two time-ordered diagrams:

1. The one you have shown:

$$ c \rightarrow s + W^+ $$
followed by:
$$ W^+ \rightarrow u + \bar s$$

2. The one everyone forgets:

$$ 0 \rightarrow u + \bar s + W^- $$
followed by:
$$ W^- + c \rightarrow s $$

So it is indeed both.